# Iterating through an array of functions where some return promises and other don't

Tags: javascript, node.js, generics, async-await, polymorphism

I'd like to know how to best iterate and execute an array of functions where some return promises and therefore we'd like to utilize `await` and most don't return promises, therefore, we set them to `async`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.steps.length; i++) {
      request = await this.steps[i].run(request);
    }
```

We need the execution to happen sequentially and therefore we utilize await because a couple of the functions make external HTTP requests but the other functions work synchronously already and therefore don't need an await but we were forced to add async in from of them so that we could write the code above which is generic.

Comment: I feel like theres got to be a better to accomplish this.. I feel like your design pattern could be tweaked in some fashion - at the end of the day I feel like this is a 'structure' type of issue.  Also, it is pretty well known that using async functions in a loop is asking for trouble and not a very good idea.

Comment: I agree, the issue is I don't know how to solve it, add another abstraction layer? The current solution violates the Liskov principle so I'm not sure what to do and that's why I posted it.

Comment: It sounds like you're focusing too much on violating principles instead of writing legible/logical code. There will always be some principle you are violating - you couldn't possibly ever please every principle (theory) out there... It's hard to offer any solution without knowing the bigger picture.

Comment: bigger picture = polymorphism where only one class out of 40 actually utilizes awaits within it and the rest are forced to be async in order to achieve the above generic code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Node.js 10.x or later you can use 
`util.types.isAsyncFunction(function foo() {});` 
to check if it's an asynchronous function. If earlier than that then you can use `theFunc.constructor.name == 'AsyncFunction'`

you can then use a ternary:

```
request = util.types.isAsyncFunction(this.steps[i].run) ? await this.steps[i].run(request) : this.steps[i].run(request)
```

Comment: That's the only option, huh?

Comment: @Rami you don't know if a function async or not. If it's async you want to await. This solution does exactly that - checks and waits when needed. I'm not sure what is your expectation.

Comment: Well, I am thinking maybe a different design pattern where SOLID principles are adhered to instead of this but this isn't the worst thing in the world.

Comment: hm, there is actually a problem with this solution. `isAsyncFunction` can detect only functions which are marked as `async`. If a function is no marked as `async` and returns a `Promise` on runtime, `isAsyncFunction` will return `false`.

Comment: The functions are all marked async so it works in my case

Comment: For SOLID, you create a new class AsyncTask that takes a function in the ctor and returns a guaranteed async function, and a class called AsyncTaskExecutor with a static method `execute` that takes an array of AsyncTasks to wrap the machinery.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your function call in Promise.resolve to guarantee it's async, and use await without worrying.  So you would just change the one line to

```
request = await Promise.resolve(this.steps[i].run(request));
```

demo

```js
(async () => {

  let steps = [
    {run: async (stuff) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r("step 1"), 700))},
    {run: (stuff) => stuff + " step 2"},
    {run: async (stuff) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(stuff + " step 3"), 100))},
    {run: (stuff) => stuff + " step 4"},
    {run: async (stuff) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(stuff + " step 5"), 300))}
  ];

  let request = "";

  for (let i = 0, s; s = steps[i]; i++) {
    request = await Promise.resolve(s.run(request));
  }

  console.log(request);
  
})();
```